# OpenOffice Calc - Transpose Columns to Rows in a distance sheet

Tags: transpose, openoffice-calc

I have opened a spreadsheet in OpenOffice Calc that contains a list of the distances between two cities.  As of now, the sheet looks like this.

[image: Open Office]

What I would like to have is something that looks like this

City_1 City_2 Distance

[image]

I'm not sure what I should be doing.  I know I want to Transpose something, but when I do that I see that I've just converted my array from being [N X M] to [M x N] when I really need [N * M x 2]

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately when output is effectively to a single column unpivoting is relatively easy. For the sake of the image I have done this is a single sheet and assume you can manage to populate what I show in ColumnsA:B starting at Row7. That just leaves a formula for C7, to be copied down:

```
=VLOOKUP(A7;$A$1:$D$4;MATCH(B7;$A$1:$D$1;0))
```

You will need to adjust the ranges to suit.

[image: SO42913203 example]